# How to create savable PDF's with Coldfusion 9

Tags: pdf-generation, save, coldfusion-9

I am creating a PDF file with  in Coldfusion 9 by merging several PDF files together into one and then offering the resulting file as a download to the user. I need to be able to make the resulting file into a Savable, Fillable PDF. Meaning that the user can enter info into the PDF file an email it back.

I know how to do this in Adobe Acrobat Pro 9: Advanced -> Extend Features in Adobe Reader...
I also know that the user will not likely have Adobe Acrobat.

I need to be able to perform the "Extend Features in Adobe Reader..." option in Coldfusion 9. Anyone know how to do that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That is not possible, outside of a Very Expensive server app from Adobe.  The extended features are an Acrobat thing not a PDF thing.  Acrobat signs the PDF with Adobe's secret key and reader sees this and flips on all the appropriate features.

If you want it, you *must* do it manually, or pay Adobe a big pile of cash.

Rather than submitting by email, why not just use the regular PDF submit mechanism?

EDIT: doc.submitForm() can submit as:

- FDF (default)
- XFDF
- HTML
- XDP
- arbitrary XML (the contents of another parameter)
- XFD
- PDF (the whole file, save rights required)